# Powering a max 360 W Ender 3 Pro with a 300 W inverter

Tags: power-supply, solar-cell, inverter, low-power, solar-energy

I’m planning on powering the Ender 3 with a 200 W solar panel with a 300 W inverter. I saw on some posts that the Ender 3 draws 500-ish watts whilst starting up but then drops to an average of 150 - 200 W.

Would the max limit of the inverter being 300 W lead to any problems whilst starting up the Ender 3 Pro?

Comment: The 200W solar panel will surely be a bigger problem.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Posts with correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar are easier to read. They also tend to get read and upvoted more frequently. I've capitalised the brand names and 'W' for watt in your post to improve legibility  See the site policy in [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on the site's help pages. You could consider explaining what an Ender 3 Pro is for those not familiar with it.

Comment: In short, no this isn't going to work, even in full sun.  A cloud would pass by, and the print would be messed up.  Consider at least *double* the capacity (400W panel, 600W inverter) *and* a suitable battery storage solution (for when that cloud sneaks by.)

Comment: The bed heater and hot end heaters will be switching off and on randomly during printing to maintain temperature - there is a good chance that both will be on at the same time, so the printer will require 500 watts at those times - the inverter will likely shut off due to the overload (ef it even makes it through the initial warm-up period).

Comment: In the interest of science, I just checked my Ender 3 power consumption while printing a small job - it draws about 10 watts while idle, 50 watts to 260 watts while printing, as the bed heater cycles, so you may be able to run it from a 300 watt inverter, but you will need a battery between the solar panel and the inverter.

Comment: Most 3D printers use a 12 or 24 V DC supply. Why are you using an inverter?

Answer (score 2):

The reason Ender 3 spikes @ 500ish Watts at startup is because its trying to heat up bed as well as nozzle at the same time which opens up both PIDs at 100%. Best way to move forward in my opinion would be to tweek PID ramp settings to limit the power consumption OR enable nozzle only after the bed has reached its reference temperature. I've done this on MArlin and can confirm this trick works.

Also, since you're using 200W solar panel for it, I'd also suggest keeping the printer inside an enclosure so that your heaters don't have to draw too much power. If you skim through MArlin's config settings file, you'll see some stepper motor parameters which can also help conserve power with "some" compromise on speed.

One you've made these firmware changes, see how much power your printer is consuming throught a print cycle and identify any spikes. If its below 200w throughout, you're good to go however as someone suggested in comment, its better to have batteries in between because you don't want your 10 hour print fail because of patch of cloud.